# Google Search Console cannot vertify my domain

Tags: dns, verification, google-search-console

I'm trying to verify my domain to Google Search Console.

I added verification code to the DNS setting on my domain.

[DNS setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOTgY.jpg)

I wonder if 'host' should be '@'.
but I cannot leave it empty, because domain service site blocked it from being empty.

So, I think 'host' is not a big issue, but google serach console cannot verify my domain.

Do you guys think there is any problem on my dns setting?

I need a help..!

Comment: Google Search Console support 2 types of domain - "root domain and all of its sub-domains" and "a specific sub-domain". I used the first type and defined a `TXT` record with `@` as host, and it works. Google Search Console verified my domain successfully. Wish this information helps.

Comment: Thank you so much shaochuancs! I'll then just wait for some time.